# ValueError: ('Could not interpret regularizer identifier:', <tf.Tensor 'AddV2:0' shape=() dtype=float32>)

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

[image]

Why I am getting this error? It's related to l2 regularizer from tensorflow.keras library.

Answer (score 0):

`kernel_regularizer` has to be a callable, not it's result. In other words, instead of

```
kernel_regularizer=l2(0.001)(x)
```

simply use

```
kernel_regularizer=l2(0.001)
```